# Story begins with rich people preparing to leave their home planet and go to a ring that orbits it (which had lasers)?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30306/12102) remind me of a book that I remember reading that began with wealthy families preparing to move from their homes on their Earth-like home planet up to a ring-type world that orbited the planet, packing their "family rockets" with their families and possessions.

I remember that the ring may have been the seat of power at one point in the planet's history, and some mention of cameras that spied on Earth and even lasers that could "enforce" the rule of law or punish misdeeds.

I vaguely remember the society being a bit like what I imagined ancient Rome was like, the wealthy with lots of leasure time on their hands, sitting around drinking wine or coffee, or walking around in robes? I don't think the story was extremely old, perhaps from 10 or 20 years ago?

I only got started reading it then for some reason had to stop.

Comment: Note that ancient Romans couldn’t drink coffee because it was not known in Europe st the time.

Comment: @ToddWilcox ha! indeed, but "I imagined" it was a bit like that ;-) in my own, personal in-universe.

Comment: I just edited to clean up the light commentary about “not being able to find it” and worked the edit into the actual question.

Comment: @Edlothiad thanks, looks good, no need for explanation.

Comment: @user14111 ancient = togas, ergo [1978](https://youtu.be/18eaNSxhK5c?t=165)

Comment: @user14111 “Ancient Rome” is generally considered to have existed from 753 BCE to 476 CE, or thereabouts.

Comment: @user14111  I imagine that some younger members of this stack exchange might possibly consider some older members to be "ancient".   I suspect that if someone says he remembers the days before spaceflight, for example, some members might call him ancient.